# Excel 2013 Averageifs

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to calculate the average of time in a column of cells if the time falls within a range in another cell.

E.g. If a patient comes in between say 6 and 8 pm I want to average data in another column.
I have managed to do this with `averageifs` but only when a single letter or digit appears in a cell, not with a range.

I have tried `=averageifs(a2:a10;b2:b10;"18:00-20:00")` but its not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using semicolons to separate your arguments, but on my system, I need to have commas.

I think the main problem is due to how your logic is laid out. With this function, you'll want to put in the same range twice, and put each end condition separately: `AVERAGEIFS(A2:A10,B2:B10,">=16:00",B2:B10,"<=18:00")`

Comment: Thanks. Its excel 365. Doesnt want to accept commas. Thanks alot. Will try that one.

Comment: Did it end up working? If not, I'll take another look and see if I'm missing something.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. Forgot to mention though that I have AM and PM times. If I have ave of AM and PM seperately it works (in 24h format) but if I try total ave with the following it does not work: AVERAGEIFS(A2:A10,B2:B10,">=16:00",B2:B10,"<=18:00", "B2:B10",">=04:00",B2:B10,"<=06:00"). Is there any way to calculate the ave excluding the 4 hours that have already been calculated (the ave time for the other 20 hours of the day)? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I can tell you the reason what you tried didn't work and give you a workaround to get everything else. I think there's a more elegant solution, but I'll have to think on it and play around a little bit. `AVERAGEIFS` uses AND criteria. So in the statement you have in your comment, you're looking for times between 16:00 and 18:00 AND times between 04:00 and 06:00. You could potentially get around this by doing the two sections separately and then combining them: `=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS(A2:A10,[criteria set 1])*COUNTIFS(A2:A10,[criteria set 1]),...))`. I'll take a look at using `OR` later.

Comment: As an aside, when you're putting in your formulas, you should use code tags, which you can get by enclosing text in the grave symbol (`)